# Can and How do you use RandomAccessFile with a file contained on an FTP server?

Tags: java, ftp, random-access

This problem pertains to Java

By using RandomAccessFile I intend to be able to also modify the file without blanking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FTP protocol only barely supports random access reads and writes.

That is to say, an FTP client can use the `REST` command to start reading or writing from a particular offset, but it will always truncate the file from that point.